# SPI data lines look identical, but results are different, how is that possible?

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, communication, digital-communications, plc

I have a golden sample system which consists of 2 devices communicating via SPI.

I swap one of the devices and bit bang the SPI to make it similar to the golden sample.

However the bit banged device doesn't receive the correct data in the MISO line.

If the signals are the same, then what could be the issue?

[image]

More info:

The devices are the Yellow/Redbeet carrier-board-h and Raspberry Pi, and NanoPi Core.

The devices are connecting with jumper wires, less than 10cm in length.

All devices get power cycled before doing this test.

**Edit**

As a second part of my experiment, I now do bit banging on the golden sample to ensure my bit banging method is correct.

I also tightened the CS because of the comments below. The output from MISO is looking correct even with these changes, so I don't believe the issue is CS.

Is there something more to SPI that I'm not aware of here?

Bit banged golden sample (with tighter CS timing), still works:
[image]

**Update 2**

This is what the signal looks like for the NanoPi Core (the device that's not working as expected) when using the driver to control the SPI:

[image]

And loosening the CS pin (still no good data):

[image]

Comment: The yellow chip select trace is different. Will it explain the difference?

Comment: There are setup and hold requirements for CS, your bitbang is probably too aggressive. The SPI driver will hold CS low (asserted) unless you change channels or configure the device through ioctl not to do this (part of ioctl is also delay between packets and delay for chip select) , sometimes a device specific driver sets this up for you automagically

Comment: @Justme do you mean the cs timing is slightly longer on the RPi? I don't believe this is the issue- the CS timing seems to make little difference from my tests. Will update post on what I mean

Comment: Instead of bitbanging, have you tried using the driver directly? Bit banging is not equivalent to peripheral control. Also, the suggestion was to actually loosen cs timing or leave cs asserted all the time.

Comment: How fast is your SPI clock

Comment: @crasic I initially tried using the driver but that didn't work, I assumed because of some minor differences in the SPI lines, will post picture. Asserting CS low all the time didn't work as well. What difference is using the driver if the signal levels and times are identical anyway? I think the answer to that question may be what I'm looking for?

Comment: _"All devices get power cycled before doing this test."_ - are your captures showing the **first** activity on the SPI bus after power up? _"...and NanoPi Core"_ - exactly which NanoPI is that? http://nanopi.io/index.html